# Detecting if device can transmit iBeacons - Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iot, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am trying to get info about type of beacons which my device can transmit. I have problem with detecting iBeacons. I can detect this type by Core Location framework which will be returning the CLBeacon object. On the other hand I discover devices using Core Bluetooth. CLBeacon and Core Bluetooth gives the founded items UUID. But there are different UUID and I don't see the way to map this values.

My next idea is to detect iBeacons depend on advertisement data returned by function

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

As I have read, the iBeacons blocks manufactured data and service data. Moreover there is no way to connect with iBeacon devices. So my question is:

Is it good idea to returning that device can transmit iBeacon depend on information above (no manufactured data, no service data, device isn't connectable)?

Or maybe there is a different way to detect iBeacons? 
As I have written above, I'm trying use Core Location but I don't have idea to map values from Core Location and Core Bluetooth information (for example via UUID)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no shared identifiers between devices detected with CoreBluetooth and CoreLocation.  Apple has gone to considerable lengths to make it impossible to correlate information from the two sources:

- Apple blocks reading the manufacturer data fields in advertisements detected by CoreBluetooth for any advertisement that matches the iBeacon format.  (It actually blanks out the contents of the data even though it is readable on other platforms like Linux, Windows and Android bluetooth stacks.)
- Apple generates a pseudo-random UUID for the CoreBluetooth device identifier that it internally maps to a hardware MAC address that is only known to the operating system.  This bluetooth device identifier has the same kind of UUID format at the ProximityUUID used with iBeacon, but the two never match for the same physical device.

Read my blog post about this here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons

You simply cannot assume that a device is a Beacon because you can see it with CoreBluetooth and it emits a manufacturer advertisement with no data and it is not connectable.  That might be true, but it might not.  There are lots of bluetooth devices out there that are not beacons and behave this way.